# Make uppercase letter have same width as number in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, width

I want to have

```
\[
\begin{array}{c}
\phantom{+} \, 39A_{12} \\
\underline{+ \, 488_{12}} \\
\phantom{+} \, 866_{12}
\end{array}
\]
```

but the spacing looks awkward with the "A". Is there a way to get upper case letters to have the same width as a digit in this case? I don't care if it's `$A$` or `$\text{A}$` or `$\mathrm{A}$`, etc., as long it stays uppercase.

Comment: `\mathtt{39A}` `\mathtt{488}`  is the easiest if tt font is acceptable

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Doing `39\mathtt{A}` may be an acceptable solution, but it still looks a bit odd (the height of `\mathtt{A}` is awkward compared with the digits). I can't do `\mathtt` for the digits.

Comment: btw, you certainly want `\mathrm{A}` and not just `A`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some possibilities, I'd probably use the last:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}


\newcommand\w[1]{\resizebox{5pt}{!}{$#1$}}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{c}
\phantom{+} \, 39A_{12} \\
\underline{+ \, 488_{12}} \\
\phantom{+} \, 866_{12}
\end{array}
\]

\[
\begin{array}{c}
\phantom{+} \, 3\mathtt{9A}_{12} \\
\underline{+ \, \mathtt{488}_{12}} \\
\phantom{+} \, \mathtt{866}_{12}
\end{array}
\]

\[
\begin{array}{c}
\phantom{+} \, 39\w{A}_{12} \\
\underline{+ \, 488_{12}} \\
\phantom{+} \, 866_{12}
\end{array}
\]

\[
\begin{array}{c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c}
 &3&9&A&_{12} \\
+&4&8&8&_{12} \\
\hline
 &8&6&6&_{12}
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

If you're happy with typewriter type letters, here's a way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,calc}
\newenvironment{dozenal}
 {\begingroup\lccode`~=`A \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\doz{A}}%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`B \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\doz{B}}%
  \mathcode`A="8000 \mathcode`B="8000 }
 {}
\newcommand{\doz}[1]{%
  \resizebox{\widthof{0}}{\heightof{0}}{\texttt{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{dozenal}
\[
\begin{array}{@{}r@{\>}r@{}}
 & 39A_{12} \\
+& 4B8_{12} \\
\hline
 & 896_{12}
\end{array}
\]
\end{dozenal}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `dozenal` environment limits the scope in which `A` and `B` denote digits to be treated differently.

Note how the input of the operation can be simplified.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably go for "poor-mans narrow", made by narrowing the bold font. As well, I believe that as digits, the letters should be always typeset upright and not italic.

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx,calc}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\ww[1]{\mathpalette\ww@{#1}}
\newcommand*\ww@[2]{\@tfor\tmp:=#2\do{\ww@@{\tmp}{#1}}}
\newcommand*\ww@@[2]{\ifcat#10#1\else\resizebox{\widthof{$#20$}}{\height}{$#2\mathbf{#1}$}\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\(
\begin{array}{r}
\phantom{+} \, \ww{39A}_{12} \\
\underline{+ \, \ww{488}_{12}} \\
\phantom{+} \, \ww{866}_{12}
\end{array}
\)

\end{document}
```

Just a short explanation:

- Macro `\ww` just takes care of proper work in superscripts, subscripts and such.
- Macro `\ww@` just takes the argument token by token and passes it to `\ww@@`.
- Macro `\ww@@` checks whether the thing it got is a digit (`\ifcat#10`), if yes, it typesets the digit (`#1`), if not, it uses resizebox and does the resize magic.